# How to convert ISheet to CT_Worksheet in c# using NPOI XSSF?

Tags: c#, npoi

I want to set the Excel View from *Normal* to *PageLayout*. In Java (PIO) there is a getCTWorksheet method, but this method doesn't seem to exist in the C# NPOI implementation.

Please suggest a way to get the CT_WorkSheet from an ISheet object, and set the appropriate view on an Excel Worksheet.

Here is how I currently set the correct view on a CT_Worksheet object I created directly.

```
CT_Worksheet ct = new CT_Worksheet();
ct = (CT_Worksheet)sheet;
CT_Workbook wrkb = wbb.GetCTWorkbook();
CT_SheetView view = ct.sheetViews.GetSheetViewArray(0);
view.view = ST_SheetViewType.pageLayout;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the NPOI designers made the `GetCTWorksheet()` method *internal*, so you cannot use it from outside the library. This might have been the intention of the POI developers as well, but Java doesn't have a concept of package-private methods.

As there doesn't seem to be an official way to access the internal classes, we'll just use *reflection* to access them.

```
var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
var sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");
var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("This is a test");

// Use reflection go call internal method GetCTWorksheet()
MethodInfo methodInfo = sheet.GetType().GetMethod("GetCTWorksheet", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var ct = (CT_Worksheet) methodInfo.Invoke(sheet, new object[] {});

CT_SheetView view = ct.sheetViews.GetSheetViewArray(0);
view.view = ST_SheetViewType.pageLayout;
```